# How to Stored symbol or Special char in postgresql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I am in trouble that how to be inserted symbol like single quotes(any other) in postgresql database. There are many solutions from this site that i have tried but my problem is not get solved.

I have checked all the symbols as below. All symbols are inserted into database correctly. But i am getting an error while inserting only on `single quotes`.

```
i.e. ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + - = { } [ ] | \ :  " < > ? ;  , . /  / *   - + .
```

Can anyone solve this issue that how to stored single quotes..?
Is that problem with `character varying,`..?  Or is their something that i have missed..? 
Following is my query

```
INSERT INTO command_tbl(sno, deviceid, command)  VALUES (111, 'c_bc0ac1fe48', 'Di1'ABC');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single quote is the delimiter for string values in SQL. So your query syntax is invalid. To put a single quote inside a string, you mst escape it by another single quote:

```
'Di1''ABC'
```

That's usually not a problem you face when programmatically inserting values in a database, because you should use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), with parameters, to do that, and the database driver deals with special characters for you.